# iPhoto-like image resizing using jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

Here is the effect that I need: http://www.agilepartners.com/blog/2005/12/07/iphoto-image-resizing-using-javascript/

Is there any jQuery plugin doing the same thing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is in your demo page. If you read the tutorial you will notice that it's just simple JavaScript code (point 3 of tutorial). Prototype is used there only to create a slider and jQuery UI also has slider that you can easily adapt to that purpose.

Check the [docs](http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider). What you need is the ability to add an event handler to slider value changes and slider value getter and this plugin provides all that for you.

Answer (score 2):

See [here](http://webdesignledger.com/tutorials/create-a-resizable-image-grid-with-jquery). Demo [here](http://demos.webdesignledger.com/jquery_image_grid/example2.htm)